# Moving undecorated JFrame using mouse event and thread to update

Tags: java, swing, jframe, inner-classes

I tend to move my undercoated `JFrame`s quite clumsily, by using creating a static reference to then a mouse event to update the `Point` location.

So In an attempt to better understand Threads , I want to move around a very simple undercoated `JFrame` as follows:

- create `JFrame`
- add `MouseListener`
- onMousePressed: `Point p = Mousevent.getPoint();`
- onMouseReleased: `Point p = Mousevent.getPoint();`

and at the same time have a thread constantly update the `JFrame`s location.

However I cant figure out why the controllerThread, wont do more than one iteration? Also an explanation to why the below code is terrible would be very much appreciated.

```
public AnimationStation() throws HeadlessException {
    P=this.getLocation();
    run();

    class ControllerThread extends Thread{
        JFrame j;
        public ControllerThread(JFrame j){
            this.j = j;

        }
        @Override
        public void run(){
            this.j.setLocation(P);
        }
    }
    ControllerThread ct = new ControllerThread(this);
    ct.run(); 
    //ct.start();


}

 @Override
public void run() {
    this.setSize(d);
    Container cp = this.getContentPane();
    P=this.getLocation();
    this.setUndecorated(true);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    this.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
           P = me.getPoint();
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
            P = me.getPoint();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
            P = me.getPoint();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {

        }
    });


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First your `ControllerThread` does not run in a different thread because you just call its `run()` method. To launch a new thread, you have to call its `start()` method.

Second, if you want to continuously move the frame while you move your mouse, you have to register a `MouseMotionListener`, a `MouseListener` only captures mouse pressed and released events (and not the mouse moved or dragged events).

**Suggested solution:**

Register a `MouseListener` to detect when dragging starts (`mousePressed()`) and a `MouseMotionListener` to detect how much the frame was dragged (`mouseDragged()`), and move the frame by the distance it was dragged:

```
public AnimationStation() {
    MouseAdapter ma = new MouseAdapter() {
        int lastX, lastY;
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            lastX = e.getXOnScreen();
            lastY = e.getYOnScreen();
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            int x = e.getXOnScreen();
            int y = e.getYOnScreen();
            // Move frame by the mouse delta
            setLocation(getLocationOnScreen().x + x - lastX,
                    getLocationOnScreen().y + y - lastY);
            lastX = x;
            lastY = y;
        }
    };
    addMouseListener(ma);
    addMouseMotionListener(ma);
}
```

Comment: Ok well that works an awful lot smoother thank you. I was trying to understand Threads though. This is obviously a much better way of moving/dragging a JFrame. seems my run method was simply missing a while loop?

Comment: @Fionán: No, your notion of a `while` loop is implicit in the Swing `EventQueue`.

Comment: @trashgod I had assumed extending from Thread an implicit while on the run() of the ct thread, however there is no change given the orginal code with either .start() or .run()..with no added while() hence the orginal question.